# Wcf get raw request from operation

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I've searched a lot for a good answer but got a lot of answers that didn't satisfy me.

We have a service with the usual operations. Inside each operation we call a different project to handle te operation and store some info of the operation inside a database.

We've got a new requirement: Store the soap message of the operation in the database too. Is it possible to receive the soap (xml) from the wcf operation? Or are event really needed?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, and if the WCF is communicating through HTTP, you could get the input stream through the context -`HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`, read it and save it somewhere.

Comment: I've tried that, Request.InputStream gives the following exception:

This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked.

Comment: Well since you're invoking `GetBufferlessInputStream`, you're already getting the request stream, right? Couldn't you just save it then?

Comment: I don't know when or where GetBufferlessInputStream is invoked. But its not done by my code.

Comment: Hmm this is weird! Which version of the .NET framework are you using? Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/09/13/accessing-httpcontext-current-request-inputstream-property-in-aspnetcompatibility-mode-throws-exception-this-method-or-property-is-not-supported-after-httprequest-getbufferlessinputstream-has-been-invoked.aspx. It says there was a related issue in 4.5 that was solved in 4.5.1

Comment: We're using target framework 4.5. So i think that's the issue. Meanwhile i've found another solution to get the raw body which works fine so far: OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()

Comment: Nice :) Post it as an answer if you can, as it may help other people.

Comment: Good suggestion, ill answer my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For myself i found this solution to get the raw soap message in framework 4.5:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()
```

Read all comments above for more details about alternatives and their problems.

Comment: That does not give you the raw message but already a parsed one.

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to use `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()` because it translates the request into Xml. When the request is JSON, I'd prefer it stay that way. I also found that, by the time an endpoint's method is invoked, `Request.InputStream` is empty---even when I have `<add key="wcf:serviceHostingEnvironment:useClassicReadEntityBodyMode" value="true" />` in web.config (FYI: the app is running .Net 4.5.2).

So, what I did was to implement `Application_BeginRequest` in Global.asax.cs. I extract the contents of `Request.InputStream` there, and save that request body to `Context.Items`. Later, in `IErrorHandler`'s `ProvideFault(...)`, I transfer the saved string over to the Exception's `Data` property so that the logging will later capture it when `HandleError(...)` runs (`Items` is empty by the time `HandleError` runs).